# Running Javascript code on a web page from command-line (i.e. Python script)

Tags: javascript, python, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a simple web page with some javascript code to parse a file and display some information from it. The file is usually larger than 250MB, I cannot upload to server. Therefore, a JS code is doing the processing. (I m not a web developer)

My question is, how can I make use of this code from a command-line for automation? For instance, a python script to provide the file path, some parameters and then get the output as text.

The motivation is to keep logic in JS only, I dont want to replicate it in Python and maintain two codes.

I could think of two methods, both are not good:

1. Run users browser in memory in Python and interact with the page? Dont know if this is possible.
2. Download JS code and run it in Python. Is there a way to do it without 3rd party packages?

I have the page running, but could not figure out how to use it from CLI.

Comment: Why not just use nodejs?

Comment: I want to keep main code on the server as it is easier to update + distribute. Can I use NodeJS to run JS on a server?

Comment: There's a reason the tagline for NodeJS is "Server-side JavaScript".

Comment: The file to process is quite large, that is why I want to process it on the client side. What I meant is to have a web app instead of local NodeJS app.
I can update js code on the page, but it is hard to update local app, therefore I want local app to be transparent, just pass some parameters